# Find real $x$ satisfying $|x + 1/x| < 4$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for $x\in\mathbb R$ if

$$ \left|x + \frac{1}{x}\right| < 4. $$

The answer is given as $(-2-\sqrt{3},-2+\sqrt{3}) \cup (2-\sqrt{3}, 2+\sqrt{3})$.

I've tried many ways but still I arrive at a different answer.

Comment: Start with $x+\frac {1}{x}<4$ or $-(x+\frac{1}{x})<4$.

Comment: What is your answer, and how did you arrive there?

Comment: hint: $\mid A\mid^2 = A^2$

Comment: @JohnJoy won't that make it more complicated than necessary?

Comment: @user251257 You're absolutely correct. I had the beginnings of a thought, but unfortunately, didn't see it through to completion :(

Comment: The graph is to be sketched at first. The region of interest is between $  (2- \sqrt 3 ,4),(2 + \sqrt 3, 4) $ around the minimum point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\;\biggl\lvert x+\dfrac1x\biggr\rvert $ is an even function of $x$, it enough to solve for $x>0$:
$$x+\frac1x<4\iff x^2-4x+1 <0\iff(x-2)^2<3\iff -\sqrt 3<x-2<\sqrt3,$$
whence the solutions, for $x>0$: $\; x\in(2-\sqrt3,2+\sqrt3)$. Completing by symmetry,we obtain the solutions for all $x$:
$$(-2-\sqrt3,-2+\sqrt3)\cup(2-\sqrt3,2+\sqrt3).$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $f(x)=x+1/x$. $f$ is odd (that is, $f(-x)=f(x)$ for every $x$), so if we solve the inequality for positive $x$, we automatically get it for negative $x$ too by symmetry.

Consider $x>0$. Note that $f'(x)=1-1/x^{2}$ and $f''(x)=3/x^{3}>0$. So the derivative is an increasing function of $x$, which is $0$ at $x=1$ (the more famous bound of $f(x)\ge2$). We deduce that $f$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$, so the solution is an open interval. Draw a picture to see this more clearly!

So consider the equation $f(x)=4$. This is a simple quadratic with roots $2\pm\sqrt{3}$. Can you do the rest?

Answer (score 0):

When you have `|X|<n where n > 0`, what that means is `X<n AND -X<4`. In this case X is $x+\frac{1}{x}$. So your problem is:
$$    |x+\frac{1}{x}|<4 -> x+\frac{1}{x}<4 \hspace{2mm} AND \hspace{2mm} -x-\frac{1}{x}<4 $$
Solve one at at time, but you'll find them very similar:
$
x+1/x<4 $ <-- Multiply by x 
$x^{2} + 1 < 4x$  <-- Subtract 4x
$x^2 - 4x + 1 < 0$  <-- Use the quadratic formula for $a=1, b=-4, c=1$
$x=2+\sqrt{3}, x=2-\sqrt{3}$
Usint the same idea for the 2nd part gives:
$-x-\frac{1}{x}<4$ <-- Multipy by x
$-x^2-1<4x$  <-- Multyp
$-x^2-4x-1<0$  <-- Use the quadratic formula for $a=-1, b=-4, c=-1$
$x=-2+\sqrt{3}, x=-2-\sqrt{3}$
The Problem is that we've just solved for '=', not '<'. At this point, it helps to make a number line and put your 'zeros' on there. Then you pick an easy value in each range to know how to put your inequality signs.
<---x-----|-----x-------|----x-----|----x-----|-----x-----|----x---->
$\hspace{6mm}-2-\sqrt{3}\hspace{4mm}-2+\sqrt{3}\hspace{10mm}0\hspace{8mm}2-\sqrt{3}\hspace{8mm}2+\sqrt{3}$
You should also note that if you substitue $x=0$, you get undefined because of the fraction.
You'll need to try values in each interval, basically and easy number where I put an 'x' on the number line. I'd suggest the following values: $x=-4,-1,-.25,.25,1,4$. Now substitute and find the ranges that are less than 4
Let $f(x)=|x+\frac{1}{x}|$, then
$f(-4)=|-4+\frac{1}{-4}|=4\frac{1}{4}$ <-- fail
$f(-1)=|-1+\frac{1}{-1}|=2$ <-- pass
$f(-.25)=|-.25+\frac{1}{-.25}|=4\frac{1}{4}$ <-- fail
$f(.25)=|.25+\frac{1}{.25}|=4\frac{1}{4}$ <-- fail
$f(1)=|1+\frac{1}{1}|=2$ <-- pass
$f(4)=|4+\frac{1}{4}|=4\frac{1}{4}$ <-- fail
To put it back on the number line...
<---f-----|-----p-------|----f-----|----f-----|-----p-----|----f---->
$\hspace{6mm}-2-\sqrt{3}\hspace{4mm}-2+\sqrt{3}\hspace{10mm}0\hspace{8mm}2-\sqrt{3}\hspace{8mm}2+\sqrt{3}$
So you answer is found in the range(s) that pass...
$$
(-2-\sqrt{3}<x<-2+\sqrt{3})U(2-\sqrt{3}<x<2+\sqrt{3})
$$

Answer (score -1):

actually it is long solution but this is the solution 
https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%20%7Cx%20%2B%201%2Fx%7C%20%3C%204%20/?origin=button

Comment: Please include a summary of the method in the link; link-only answers are likely to be deleted.

Comment: Bernard has put it beautifully.